# Dissolve Edges in Text Object

Tags: edges, text-object

I have a *Text Object* that I converted to a mesh:

[image: Before]

I would like to reduce all the unnecessary edges like in the picture below (including the two I could not get rid of):

[image: After]

But instead of step by step dissolving edges (and then end up with some undissovable ones), I would like to achieve this in a simpler way.

Select the complete *Text* mesh (not just one letter) and dissolve all edges. 
Unfortunately this does not work like that.

Also the *Decimate* object modifier just ends up distorting the Text/Font.

Is there an easy way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Ngons with holes are not supprted yet (2.77), so it's not strange that there be some edges that you won't be able to dissolve.

Comment: As Carlo said you can't have edge islands in the middle of ngons that are totally disconnected from the surrounding edges. Best you could do is 'minimize the damage' and manually choose where you place them so they look better. For example in the A I would place them at the bottom over the horizontal arm

Comment: I would leave it where you have more segments but they're all quads/tris. A more orderly mesh is better than a minimal one.